# Are there any popular C/C++ encryption libraries that support Rijndael-160?

Tags: c++, c, encryption

I need an encryption library that supports Rijndael with 160-bit key and 128-bit block size. I can't find any libraries that explicitly mention the full flexibility of Rijndael or 160-bit keys; most just mention AES support.

Comment: Never mind. I was unable to find a major crypto library that support Rijndael-160, and this community is dead, so I wrote my own implementation.